# ThreadAbortException in at System.Net.UnsafeNclNativeMethods.OSSOCK.recv

Tags: .net, windows, sockets

Suddenly, this exception started happening in my program. Any ideas, what can be the reason?
Running on .NET 4.0

```
   at System.Net.UnsafeNclNativeMethods.OSSOCK.recv(IntPtr socketHandle, Byte* pinnedBuffer, Int32 len, SocketFlags socketFlags)
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Receive(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size, SocketFlags socketFlags, SocketError& errorCode)
   at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
   at System.Net.PooledStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
   at System.Net.Connection.SyncRead(HttpWebRequest request, Boolean userRetrievedStream, Boolean probeRead)
   at System.Net.ConnectStream.ProcessWriteCallDone(ConnectionReturnResult returnResult)
   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
   at System.Net.WebClient.GetWebResponse(WebRequest request)
   at System.Net.WebClient.DownloadBits(WebRequest request, Stream writeStream, CompletionDelegate completionDelegate, A
syncOperation asyncOp)
   at System.Net.WebClient.UploadValues(Uri address, String method, NameValueCollection data)
```

Comment: Looks like some code somewhere is calling [Thread.Abort](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.abort.aspx), which is a bad, bad, bad thing. Do you have any Thread.Abort calls in your code? If not, then the problem is in some third-party code, which would be harder to track down.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There was a Thread.Abort() call deep inside of guts of the program. That was the reason.

Answer (score 0):

My scenario was like this; IIS is the main process. I scheduled IIS periodic recycling, like 5 minutes. Mail is sent by a thread of the main process (wp3.exe). When recycling occurs, the thread cannot send mail because the main thread was aborted. I extended the recycling period.